# how to wrap each nested child element passed to component in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I just want to wrap each passed component element into "div" with  "some" css class.
For example:
I passed to component 'component-that-wrap-children' three elements:

```
 <component-that-wrap-children>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
      <div>text</div>
      <some-component>another text</some-component>
    </component-that-wrap-children>
```

And then I want it becomes:

```
<component-that-wrap-children>
    <div class="some"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/></div>
    <div class="some"><div>text</div></div>
    <div class="some"><div>another text</div></div>
</component-that-wrap-children>
```

Is there way to do it?

**UPD** With React I can do it like so:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

class ComponentThatWrapChildren extends Component {
    render() {
        let rows = this.props.children.map((child, i) => <div key={i} className="some">{child}</div>);

        return (<div>{rows}</div>);
    }
}

ComponentThatWrapChildren.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node
};

export default ComponentThatWrapChildren;
```

Comment: You can use <ng-content></ng-content> directive, but it will be possible wrap only all elements

Comment: Can I get elements from "<ng-content></ng-content>" then wrap each and then repase with it  "<ng-content></ng-content>" ?